# Find the average of fields in column

Tags: linux, awk

I have have an input file like this in that file each column is separated by tab space

```
22 2222 .  T    C   .   .   ;AA=1;AFE=1;ASNE=1;EUN=1;AFW=1;MED=1;LAT=1;
22 222  .  T    C   .   .   ;AA=2;AFE=2;ASNE=2;EUN=2;AFW=2;MED=2;LAT=2;
```

and I need the output as follows

```
22 2222 .  T    C   .   . ;AA=1;AFE=1;ASNE=1;EUN=1;AFW=1;MED=1;LAT=1;AVG=1;
22 222  .  T    C   .   . ;AA=2;AFE=2;ASNE=2;EUN=2;AFW=2;MED=2;LAT=2;AVG=2;
```

Where AVG is the average of all fields in 8th column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is on way:

```
awk '{c=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){split($i,d,"=");c+=d[2]}$NF="AVG="c/(NF-2)FS}1' FS=';' OFS=';' file
    22 2222 .  T    C   .   .   ;AA=1;AFE=1;ASNE=1;EUN=1;AFW=1;MED=1;LAT=1;AVG=1;
    22 222  .  T    C   .   .   ;AA=2;AFE=2;ASNE=2;EUN=2;AFW=2;MED=2;LAT=2;AVG=2;
```